# $n$th derivative of $\ln(x)e^{2x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I was asked to calculate the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=\ln(x)e^{2x}$, and my solution was to use the [Leibniz formula](https://www.cuemath.com/calculus/leibniz-rule/), so we have:

$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}C^{k}_{n}.\frac{(-1)^{k-1}.(k-1)!}{x^k}.2^{n-k}.e^{2x}$.

But I don't know how I can calculate this sum.

Comment: Note that the term corresponding to $k=0$ is undefined; the sum should start at $k=1$ and one has to add the term $2^ne^{2x}\ln x $ "by hand".

Comment: With CAS I have:$$-2^n e^{2 x} \gamma -(-2)^n e^{2 x} n \Gamma (n) \Gamma (-n,2 x)+2^n e^{2 x} H_n+\frac{2^{1+n} e^{2 x} x \Gamma (1+n) \, _2F_2(1,1;2,2+n;-2 x)}{\Gamma (2+n)}-2^n e^{2 x} \ln (2)$$

Answer (score 2):

In general if $ f(x)= g(x)e^{2x}$ then we have the formal identity

$$ D^N f= e^{2x} [(D+2)^N g(x)]$$ which by a formal extension of the binomial expansion becomes $$e^{2x} \sum_{k=0}^N 2^{N-k} D^k g(x)$$

In your case $g(x)= \ln (x)$, so $Dg= 1/x, D^2 g= (-1)x^{-2}, D^3g= 2! x^{-3}$ etc.

That is, $ D^kg= (-1)^{k-1} (k-1)! x^{-k}$ for $k>0$.

P.S. As noted by others, of course $k=0$ is a different case.